# Calling Some activity outside activity group

Tags: android

I Have one activity group. Consists of around six activity **A >B >C >D >E > F**
Its working fine in activity group. With this is use to navigate from one activity to another.

```
     View view = ConsultationGroup.group.getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("newsdisplay", Home1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)).getDecorView();  
     ConsultationGroup.group.replaceView(view);
```

**Now the problem is:**

I need to call activity F from activity E and it should not be in the activity group. Hence i need to call the activity outside the actvivity group. I am using this method.

```
     Intent  Home1=new Intent(E.this,F.class);
     startActivity(Home1);
```

But the problem is device back key is not behaving properly when again i am coming back to activity E from F. When i hit 5 times back key then it takes me to Activity A. It should behave like F>E>D>C>B>A

I want to save the activity group state on activity E when going to activity F and when coming back it should behave normal when pressing back key.

Pls solve it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to post a little more code. 
Where have you put this code?

```
 Intent  Home1=new Intent(E.this,F.class);
 startActivity(Home1);
```

i.e. in which lifecycle method?

Comment: On click of button..when i need to go from one activity to another.

Comment: Check out the link below... See how they've used the lifecycle methods of the ActivityGroup to retain the state of the activities. 
You probably need to do something similar...
http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/android/core/java/android/app/ActivityGroup.java.shtml

Comment: And I have to agree a little with @Peter Knego here. No one can *solve* your problem or give you working code. They can at best point you in the right direction. Be a little generous. The occasional upvote or accept won't hurt you. Consider it a thank you for someone who has take the time to look into your problem.